# git version control : permisssion denied

Tags: git, github

I'm getting an error while pushing my code to Github saying permission denied as I do not have the correct access rights.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+permission+denied+publickey

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you use HTTPS? If so, check the password when you are asked to enter your GitHub account and password.

   - Tips: Sometime Windows will auto fill the password when you have entered the password once before. But if you type the wrong password at the first time, it will always go wrong because Windows type it automaticly. **What you need to do** is clean the saved password.
2. If you use SSH, this https://help.github.com/ssh-issues/ will help you.